# Get original dictionary from dict.AsQueryable()

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, iqueryable

I have a generic dictionary that pass to a method which only accepts `IQueryable` as a parameter

Is it possible to cast the queryable back to the original dictionary? And I don't mean creating a new dictionary with `.ToDictionary(...)`

```
private static void Main()
{

    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    dict.Add(1,1);

    SomeMethod(dict.AsQueryable());

}

public static void SomeMethod(IQueryable dataSource)
{
    // dataSource as Dictionary<int, int> --> null
    var dict = dataSource.???
}
```

I know in this simple example this does not make much sense. But in the big picture I have an interface which requires me to return an `IQueryable` as a dataSource. On implementation returns a dictionary. On a different place in my code I have classes that process the dataSources.

The processor knows that the dataSource will be an Dictionary but I don't want to have the overhead for creating another Dictionary if I already have one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.AsQueryable()` extension method returns an instance of the [`EnumerableQuery<T>` wrapper class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/SequenceQuery.cs) if it is called on something that was not already an `IQueryable<T>`.

This wrapper class has an `.Enumerable` property with `internal` access that provides access to the original object that `.AsQueryable()` was called on. So you *could* do this to get back your original dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict.Add(1,1);
var q = dict.AsQueryable();



Type tInfo = q.GetType();
PropertyInfo pInfo = tInfo.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                         BindingFlags.Instance)
                          .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Enumerable");
if (pInfo != null)
{
    object originalDictionary = pInfo.GetValue(q, null);

    Console.WriteLine(dict == originalDictionary);  // true
}
```

However, this is generally a pretty bad idea. `internal` members have their access restricted for a reason, and I don't think there's any guarantee that the internal implementation of `.AsQueryable()` won't change at some point in the future. So your best bet is to either find a way to make the original dictionary accessible, or go ahead and make a new one.

---

One possible workaround (which is not great) is to make your own wrapper class to carry the dictionary along:

```
private class DictionaryQueryHolder<TKey, TValue> : IQueryable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary { get; private set; }
    private IQueryable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> Queryable { get; set; }

    internal DictionaryQueryHolder(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        Dictionary = dictionary;
        Queryable = dictionary.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Queryable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return Queryable.Expression; }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return Queryable.ElementType; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return Queryable.Provider; }
    }
}
```

This would both act as a wrapper for the dictionary's `IQueryable<T>` and provide access to the original dictionary. But on the other hand, anyone trying to retrieve the dictionary would have to know what the generic type parameters were (e.g. `<string, string>`, `<int, string>`, etc.) in order to cast it successfully.

Comment: The hint with the private `Enumerable` field worked. I even included a fallback in my code (`if (pInfo == null) then create a new dictionary and add the KeyValuePairs manually`) to maintain compatibility with future versions.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that IQueryable wraps itself around the Dictionary rather than being like IEnumerable<> over IDictionary<>, where you could cast it back.

You can certainly find out if the type wrapped is a dictionary if you know the types involved:

```
public bool isDictionary<T>(object obj) {
    return obj.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.Contains(typeof(T));
}

isDictionary<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(dataSource);
```

If you don't mind reaching into the objects internals, you could use the private `Enumerable` field on `EnumerableQuery` to get a version of (possibly) the original dictionary back as an `IEnumerable<>`

But to actually convert from an `EnumerableQuery<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` hiding under an `IQueryable` without doing that I think you'd have to just take the hit and create a new dictionary from it.